# Server cannot clear headers after HTTP headers have been sent

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

In order to download a file i have written the following code

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post | HttpVerbs.Get)] public ActionResult Download(string fileName) { 
    try { 
        string filepath = @"C:\shadow_copy.rar";

        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= " + fileName.TrimEnd());
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileName.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.WriteFile(filepath.TrimEnd());
        Response.End();

    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        //
    }

    return Redirect("http://mysite.com");
}
```

I have also used

if (!Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected) // Will not be called Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com")

but it is showing the error

"Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent."

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? To download a file or redirect the user. You have to choose one to the other.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot redirect after downloading the File, you are attempting to perform 2 actions where you can only do the first.

I suggest that you download the file in a new (popup) window and redirect the main page if required.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, it's a bit easier:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post | HttpVerbs.Get)] 
public ActionResult Download(string fileName) 
{ 
    string filepath = @"C:\shadow_copy.rar";
    return File(filepath, "application/octet-stream", "shadow_copy.rar");
}
```

Also you cannot redirect after the download.

Answer (score 0):

I have got this exception when Downloading multiple excel files. first file downloaded successfully but second file download time got this exception. I was written following code.

```
   public ActionResult CmsBulkUploadDownloadExcelSelectedTemplateForGpro(int CmsYear, string TinsList)
    {

        var username = CurrentUser.UserName;
        List<string> TinList = TinsList.Split('|').ToList();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        if (TinList.Count <= 0)
        {
            // Need Select Aleast one Tin
        }
        else
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Tin", typeof(string));
            foreach (var item in TinList)
            {

                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Tin"] = item;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

        }
        List<CMSFacilityData> list = new List<CMSFacilityData>();
        list = FacilityCMSSubmissionBL.GetQMSelectedTinsMeasures(CmsYear, dt)
        ViewBag.ex = "";
        var iteratecount = Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal(list.Count) / 4);
        var skip = 0;
        var next = 4;
        for (int x = 0; x < iteratecount; x++)
        {

            try
            {


            var list1 = list.Skip(skip).Take(next).ToList();

            string myName = Server.UrlEncode("MIPS" + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss-") + Convert.ToString(x+1)+".xlsx");
            var strAppPath = System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath.ToString();
            if (strAppPath == "/")
            {
                strAppPath = "";
            }
            var workbook = new XLWorkbook();

            var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("PQRS Excel Data");
            // This is to ensure that this column is text
            worksheet.Column(1).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "@";
            worksheet.Column(2).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "@";
            worksheet.Column(3).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "@";
            worksheet.Column(4).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "@";
            worksheet.Column(5).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "@";
            worksheet.Column(6).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "@";
            worksheet.Column(7).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "@";
            worksheet.Column(8).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "@";
            worksheet.Column(9).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "@";
            worksheet.Column(10).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "@";
            worksheet.Column(11).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "@";
            worksheet.Column(12).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "@";
            worksheet.Column(13).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "@";
            /// worksheet.Column(13).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "@";


            //worksheet.Column(10).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "@";
            //  worksheet.Column(1).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss";

            var i = 1; //max 1048576
            do
            {
                var r = worksheet.Row(i);
                for (int c = 1; c < 14; c++)
                {
                    r.Cell(c).SetDataType(XLCellValues.Text);
                    // r.Cell(c).SetValue("");
                    var j = i - 1;
                    switch (c)
                    {

                        case 1:
                            //TIN 1
                            r.Cell(c).SetValue(Convert.ToString(list1[j].TINNum));
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            ///Measure Number -2
                            r.Cell(c).SetValue(Convert.ToString(list1[j].Mes_Number));
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            ///Total_numberof_Exams_mygroup_performed -3
                            r.Cell(c).SetValue(Convert.ToString(list1[j].measCount));
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            ///Number_of_Exams_Submitted_OLD -4
                            r.Cell(c).SetValue(Convert.ToString(list1[j].RecordsCount));
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            ///Number_of_Exams_Submitted_NEW -5
                            r.Cell(c).SetValue("");
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            ///Submitted_Hundred_Percent_OLD -6
                            r.Cell(c).SetValue(Convert.ToString(list1[j].HundredPercentOfSubmit != null ? (list1[0].HundredPercentOfSubmit == true ? "Y" : "N") : ""));
                            break;

                        case 7:
                            ///Submitted_Hundred_Percent_NEW -7
                            r.Cell(c).SetValue("");
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            ///Selected_for_CMS_submission_OLD -8
                            r.Cell(c).SetValue(Convert.ToString(list1[j].SelectedForCMS != null ? (list1[0].SelectedForCMS == true ? "Y" : "N") : ""));

                            break;
                        case 9:
                            ///Selected_for_CMS_submission_NEW -9
                            r.Cell(c).SetValue("");

                            break;
                        case 10:
                            ///Performance_rate -10
                            r.Cell(c).SetValue(Convert.ToString(list1[j].Performance_rate));

                            break;

                        case 11:
                            ///Decile -11
                            r.Cell(c).SetValue(Convert.ToString(list1[j].Decile_Val));

                            break;

                        case 12:
                            ///Completeness -12
                            r.Cell(c).SetValue(Convert.ToString(list1[j].Reporting_Rate));

                            break;
                        case 13:
                            ///isEndtoEndReported -12
                            r.Cell(c).SetValue(Convert.ToString(list1[j].isEndtoEndReported == true ? "Y" : "N"));

                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                }


                i++;
            } while (i < list1.Count);
            var k = list1.Count;
            if (list1.Count <= 100000)
                do
                {
                    var r = worksheet.Row(k);
                    for (int c = 1; c < 13; c++)
                    {
                        r.Cell(c).SetDataType(XLCellValues.Text);
                        r.Cell(c).SetValue("");
                    }
                    k++;
                }
                while (k < 100000);
            worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = "TIN";
            worksheet.Cell("B1").Value = "Measure_Number";
            worksheet.Cell("C1").Value = "Total_numberof_Exams_mygroup_performed";
            worksheet.Cell("D1").Value = "Number_of_Exams_Submitted_OLD";
            worksheet.Cell("E1").Value = "Number_of_Exams_Submitted_NEW";
            worksheet.Cell("F1").Value = "Submitted_Hundred_Percent_OLD";
            worksheet.Cell("G1").Value = "Submitted_Hundred_Percent_NEW";
            worksheet.Cell("H1").Value = "Selected_for_CMS_submission_OLD";
            worksheet.Cell("I1").Value = "Selected_for_CMS_submission_NEW";
            worksheet.Cell("J1").Value = "Performance_rate";
            worksheet.Cell("K1").Value = "Decile";
            worksheet.Cell("L1").Value = "Completeness";
            worksheet.Cell("M1").Value = "EndtoEndReporting";

            //worksheet.Cell("M1").Value = "Measure_Extension_Num";
            //worksheet.Cell("N1").Value = "Extension_Response_Value";
            //worksheet.Cell("O1").Value = "Exam_Unique_ID";
            worksheet.Columns().AdjustToContents();
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

            stream=(MemoryStream)GetStream(workbook);
            Response.Clear();

             Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();

                Response.Buffer = true;
                 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myName);
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
                Response.Flush();
                //Response.Clear();
                Response.End();
                Response.Buffer = false;
                stream.Dispose();
            stream.Close();


                //workbook.Dispose();

                skip = skip + 4;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
        return PartialView("_BulkCmsDataFileUpload");
    }
```